# Count two columns in the same table and then count both as total

Tags: sql, mysql, join, count, distinct

**Project**

| project_id | project_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Crispy |
| 2 | Smile |
| 3 | Genie |

**Artist**

| artist_id | artist_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Lisa Simpson |
| 2 | John Smith |
| 3 | Sally Winter |

**Credit**

| credit_id | credit_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Producer |
| 2 | Vocalist |
| 3 | Writer |
| 4 | Mixer |

**Song**

| song_id | song_name | project_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | Hello | 1 |
| 12 | Goodie | 3 |
| 30 | Butterfly | 2 |
| 55 | Lollipop | 1 |

**Remix**

| remix_id | remix_name | project_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Hello (Extended Mix) | 1 |
| 22 | Goodie (Bad Remix) | 3 |
| 31 | Butterfly (Sugar Remix) | 2 |
| 45 | Lollipop (Radio Mix) | 1 |

**Credit_To_Artist**

| autoid | credit_id | artist_id | song_id | remix_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 23 | null |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | null | 10 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 55 | null |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | null | 45 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 23 | null |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 12 | null |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 30 | null |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 30 | null |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | null | 31 |

I want to show a list of Projects in alphabetical order, that show a COUNT of how many Songs OR Remixes that particular Artist has.

**The output I am wanting to achieve is this:** (Artist ID = 1)

| artist_id | project_id | project_name | songcount | remixcount | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Crispy | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | Smile | 1 | 1 | 2 |

What single query would accomplish this result? I have attempted the below query, which gets the total number of songs fine, but it's not working for remixcount, and I'm not sure how to add those together to get the total.

Thank you in advance.

```
SELECT a.artist_id, p.project_id, p.project_name,
COUNT(DISTINCT c2a.song_id) as songcount, 
COUNT(DISTINCT c2a.remix_id) as remixcount 
FROM `Project` p
LEFT JOIN `Song` s ON s.project_id = p.project_id
LEFT JOIN `Remix` rm ON rm.project_id = p.project_id
LEFT JOIN `Credit_To_Artist` c2a ON c2a.song_id = s.song_id
INNER JOIN `Artist` a ON a.artist_id = c2a.artist_id
WHERE c2a.artist_id = 1
GROUP BY p.project_id
ORDER BY p.project_name ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is very delicate, because when you have aggregation, and lots of tables to be joined, it's easy to mess up, as the first (wrong) impulsive act is to join all tables together and then stick the count directly, which is not exactly the best way to proceed.

Here's the mental process I'd follow:

- First of all you get to consider the master table that has all ids, namely "*credit_to_artist*". You notice that songs and remixes are found on staggered records, and the only way we can associate them together is through project ids.
- So we need song project ids from the "*song*" table, and remix project ids from the "*remix*" table. We apply the corresponding two left joins. And we can use `COALESCE(r.project_id, s.project_id)` to just use one single field for project ids.
- Then you notice that also project names are needed, so you add up a join operation to gather project names from the "*project*" table.

Once you have gone through these steps, you can finally apply the aggregation, whereas the aggregated fields are:

- `COUNT(song_id)`: the amount of songs,
- `COUNT(remix_id)`: the amount of remixes,
- `COUNT(song_id) + COUNT(remix_id)`: the total

and your non-aggregated fields, that should go in the `GROUP BY` clause, are:

- "*artist_id*"
- `COALESCE(r.project_id, s.project_id)`, aka the unified project id
- "*project_name*"

Here's the full query:

```
SELECT cta.artist_id,
       COALESCE(r.project_id, s.project_id)   AS project_id,
       p.project_name                         AS project_name,
       COUNT(cta.song_id)                     AS song_count,
       COUNT(cta.remix_id)                    AS remix_count,
       COUNT(cta.song_id)+COUNT(cta.remix_id) AS total
FROM      credit_to_artist cta
LEFT JOIN remix r
       ON cta.remix_id = r.remix_id
LEFT JOIN song s
       ON s.song_id = cta.song_id
INNER JOIN project p
        ON COALESCE(r.project_id, s.project_id) = p.project_id
GROUP BY cta.artist_id,
         COALESCE(r.project_id, s.project_id),
         p.project_name
ORDER BY artist_id, project_id
```

The last `ORDER BY` clause is entirely optional. It's just for visualization purposes.

**Output**:

| artist_id | project_id | song_count | remix_count | total | project_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 4 | Crispy |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | Smile |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | Crispy |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | Smile |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | Genie |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iKcXGtuSteJqWK3bcNaYpU/0).